# Javascript functions executes on second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-webcam-plugin

I am using the [jQuery webcam](https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam) plugin to capture an image from the webcam. I have all script files in order. This button is used to make the `capture()` call to get the webcam's snapshot:

```
<input id="capture" type="submit" value="Capture my shot!" onclick="webcam.capture();" />
```

The webcam is called through the following function:

```
$("#cam-space").webcam({
    width: 560,
    height: 420,
    mode: "save",
    swffile: "javascript/jscam.swf",
    onTick: function (remain) {
        if (0 == remain) {
            jQuery("#timer-status").text("Cheese!");
        } else {
            jQuery("#timer-status").text(remain + " seconds remaining...");
        }
    },
    onSave: function () {
    },
    onCapture: function () {
        webcam.save("/capture/image");
    },
    debug: function () { },
    onLoad: function () { }
});
```

My problem is that when I clicked the button the first time, I'm getting the following error in Chrome's debugger:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (onclick)`

But when I click it the second time, it works and takes the snapshot. What may be the problems?

Comment: just add all your script in `$(document).ready()`, if you haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `webcam.capture()` won't be defined until the Webcam plugin finishes loading. Instead of using an `onclick` attribute on the button, you should bind the event listener after the plugin is loaded:

```
$("#cam-space").webcam({
    /* ... */
    onLoad: function() {
        $("#capture").on("click", webcam.capture);
    }
    /* ... */
});
```

Additionally, as Mritunjay [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351639/javascript-functions-executes-on-second-time/25351710#comment39526307_25351639), make sure your `$("#cam-space").webcam()` statement is contained in `$(document).ready(function() { });`.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. I also had to add a separate `click()` method to call the `capture()` function (besides the `on()` method).